# Open a popup by clicking on a button

Tags: html, css, popup

I have a link that opens a small popup (not a new tab) to a page. 
I would like to integrate this function into a button. Unfortunately this doesn't work as hoped.

Good example link:

```
<a href='#' onclick='window.open **
("https://google.com","mywindow", 
"menubar=1,resizable=1,width=500,height=500")'>
Link</a>
```

Current button that should do the same:

```
<form>
  <input class="btnstylega" onclick="window.location.href='https://google.com'" type="button" value="Link" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why you not try:

```
  <form><input class="btnstylega" onclick="window.open('https://google.com','mywindow', 
  'menubar=1,resizable=1,width=500,height=500')" 
  type="button" value="Neue Versicherung hinzufügen" /></form>
```

Comment: Thank you! 
That's the solution I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `_blank` with the `target` attribute; this will open a new tab:

```
<form>
  <input class="btnstylega" type="button" value="Neue Versicherung hinzufügen" target="_blank" />
</form>
```

Or if you want to open a new window, use the `onClick` attribute:

```
<button class="button" onClick="window.open('http://www.example.com');">
     <span class="icon">Open</span>
</button>
```

Here, do NOT forget the quotation marks around the `"window.open('http://www.example.com');"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are setting the window location in one and not creating a new window.

This amended code should work as intended:

```html
<form><input class="btnstylega" 
onclick="window.open('https://google.com','mywindow', 
'menubar=1,resizable=1,width=500,height=500')" 
type="button" value="Link" /></form>
```